Calling CMake with Start-Process in GitLab CI job doesn't appear to use passed arguments
I am very new to Powershell especially in the context of GitLab CI configuration.
My repo has the following structure:
*
|
+ - .gitlab-ci.yml
|
+ - CMakeLists.txt
|
+ - .gitmodules
|
+ - .configs
|      |
|      + - .basic_config.yml
|      |
|      + - .dep_1_config.yml
|      |
|     ...
|      |
|      + - .dep_N_config.yml
|
+ - deps
     |
     + - submodule_1
     |
    ...
     |
     + - submodule_N

In my CMakeLists.txt I add (based on a -D flag for the CMake command call) each submodule 1..N with add_subdirectory("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/submodule_X").
The .configs directory contains a basic CI configuration used by all others and a single configuration file per dependency (represented by a corresponding git submodule, e.g. .dep_3_config.yml takes care of the CI configuration for submodule_3). All dependency configs are then called inside the main gitlab-ci.yml.
.basic_config.yml
# Currently used only for experimentation
.build-setup:
  before_script:
    - git config --system core.longpaths true

# The main base configuration for any building CI job
.build:
  variables:
    DepName: ""
    # DepCmakeArg will be overwritten by inheriting CI config of a dependency and set to the CMake cmd arguments required for its configuration
    DepCmakeArg: -DBuildDEFAULT=ON
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "debug" | $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "main"
  script:
    - |
      New-Item -Path "." -Name "build" -ItemType "directory"
      
      # main == release but we have to rename it to keep it consistent
      # This check should be dropped in the future (perhaps) for the tag
      # check and proper release (special type of CI job)
      if($env:CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME -eq "main"){
        $env:CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME = "release"
      }
    
      # Configuration step with CMake
      Start-Process cmake -ArgumentList "-Bbuild -G ""Visual Studio 16 2019"" -S$PWD -DCMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES=""$env:CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"" $env:DepCmakeArg" -NoNewWindow

      # Building step with CMake
      Start-Process cmake -ArgumentList "--build build --target ALL_BUILD --config $env:CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" -NoNewWindow

# Sets up the artifacts directory to ensure common structure for all artifacts so that they can be easily integrated as dependencies in other projects
.artifact-setup:
  variables:
    DepName: "DEFAULT"  # Will be overriden by the local CI job variable with the same name
    ArtifactRoot: "artifacts"
  script:
    - |
      if($CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME -eq "main"){
        $ArtifactRoot = "${ArtifactRoot}/release"
      }else{
        $ArtifactRoot = "${ArtifactRoot}/${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}"
      }
      mkdir -p ${ArtifactRoot}\lib\
      mkdir -p ${ArtifactRoot}\bin\
      mkdir -p ${ArtifactRoot}\include\${DepName}

# Copy the artifacts from ArtifactRoot to a specific location set by ArtifactRootCopyDestination
# Can be used e.g. to provide artifacts locally to CI jobs instead of forcing those to trigger download
.artifact-copy:
  script:
    - |
      Copy-Item -Path "$env:ArtifactRoot" -Destination "$env:ArtifactRootCopyDestination" -Recurse -Container:$true -force
      Get-Date | Out-File "$env:ArtifactRootCopyDestination/$env:CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME/artifacts.txt" -NoNewLine -Force

An example for a dependency is OpenCV, which I build (using some CMake variables inside my CMakeLists.txt:
.opencv_config.yml
# Add base configuration
include:
  - local: .configs/.base_config.yml

.build-opencv:
  stage: build
  variables:
    DepName: opencv
    # Specifying CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX makes sure that the generated artifacts are referencing relatively the installation dir
    # In case of OpenCV if not used and even if the files are properly copied, the ".cmake" config files inside the installed
    # lib dir will reference <opencv-install-dir>/<arch>/<compiler>
    DepCmakeArg: -DBuildOpenCV=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="./install/"
    ArtifactRoot: !reference [.artifact-setup, variables, ArtifactRoot]
    GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
    GIT_SUBMODULE_PATHS: deps/opencv
    ArtifactRootCopyDestination: "${COMMON_DEPS}/opencv/4.10.0/cpu/"
  artifacts:
    # Upload everything until issue fixed
    untracked: true
    #paths:
    #  - artifacts
    #  - "./deps/build/*"
    when: always
  script:
    - ls
    - !reference [.build, script]

The call for that dependency inside my CI configuration:
.gitlab-ci.yml
stages:
  - build

include:
  - local: .configs/.opencv_config.yml

build-opencv-release:
  stage: build
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "main"
  variables: !reference [.build-opencv, variables]
  artifacts: !reference [.build-opencv, artifacts]
  script:
    - !reference [.build-opencv, script]

I had it all working until I started adding the command line arguments for CMake with the option to adjust those using CI variables. Then I was forced to switch from just calling CMake, e.g.
script:
  - cmake -Bbuild -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -S. ..........

to using a multiline script as described in my .basic_config.yml.
When I run the CI job I get
$ # Main == release but we have to rename it to keep it consistent # collapsed multi-line command
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.17763.0 to target Windows 10.0.14393.
Error: could not load cache
...

without the actual building step producing any binaries (that was not the case before I switched to Start-Process!).
I am not sure what's going on.
PS: The ArtifactRootCopyDestination is for creating a local copy of the artifact. Some of the dependencies produce artifacts that are too big to upload so project that are using those have the option to use a local version (everything is stored and executed on an executor I have set up myself so the CI has access to these resources).
